# How to sum up different tags from different containers in one GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a question.
I have multiple domains on all of them I have set up cross-domain tracking. The domains also have multiple tags in GTM Containers.
I just want to put all of their tags in one GTM container (Master container) in which I have set up cross-domain tracking.
If anyone has some easy and short way, please tell.

Comment: If you're asking about an easy way to combine the different GTM Containers: I would recommend using the "Import/Export" functionality.
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106997?hl=en

Comment: I have tried this but When it comes to publishing, It showed a lot of Duplications Errors.

Answer (score 1):

Just as ptts commented, you merge the containers with the import feature and resolve all conflicts manually. You will have to go through each tag and make sure it makes sense and is not duplicated.

After each merge, you have to conduct a solid regression testing. Depending on the number of tags and containers to merge, you may consider also automating this regression.

However, there is a good reason for there to be different GTM containers for different subdomains.And it's a lot harder to split it than to consolidate. For example, I've devised a plan to split a client's GTM container into seven containers for a few months.

Why would one want to split a container? There are many reasons, really. But the most important reasons are:

1. GTM containers have limited size, when that size is reached, you won't be able to publish unless you start removing properties from it.
2. A lot of GTM triggers add global listeners to the DOM, each of which influences page load and render speed, taxes clients' resources. It's normally insignificant, but with a large container that includes logic for several subdomains, it gets noticeable.
3. When containers are properly split, it's much easier to manage them. One may even consider to have one container to be a technical hub to contain set up for the rest of containers and some global tags. Just to keep shared logic in one place and not have to go through each container and make the same change. Yes, you can use multiple containers on one page.
4. Access management problems may occur when you need to share GTM of only one subdomain/site with a contractor or a third-party to conduct some POC.

I could probably find more reasons for splitting, but will stop on these.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you don't have GTM premium (comes with GA premium, which is expensive). But if you do, you get a feature called GTM zones.

This lets one GTM container import another and run it on the page.

Which means that you could have a site specific GTM container on each site, but that could import the master GTM container, using a zone, for all the generic tags you have that you want running on all sites.